# Why does my infragistics ValueList dot produce or show a dropdown

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

I am trying to make a dropdown cell/column in an `UltraWinGrid`. When I run the program and click on the `PRCLEVEL` cell it doesn't dropdown and it doesn't show anything. I also cannot type anything into the cell. Here is the entire form:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports Centerprism.Data
Imports Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid
Imports Infragistics.Win
Imports OrderEntry.InfragisticsHelpers
Imports SharpUtilities, Prism.Core.Sql

Public Class frmPriceLevelAssignmentBySite
    Private mdsPriceLevels As DataSet = Nothing
    Dim mobjGlobals As Centerprism.Data.Interfaces.IRunPlainOldSql2
    Private _vl As ValueList = New ValueList()

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        mobjGlobals = WebConnectionFactory.GlobalsWebProvider
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmPriceLevelAssignmentBySite_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

            Dim itemNumber As Integer
            For Each prclevel As String In GetPriceLevels()
               _vl.ValueListItems.Add(itemNumber,prclevel)
                itemNumber += 1
            Next

            BindGrid()

            Cursor = Cursors.Default
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorLogging.LogError(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub BindGrid()
        mdsPriceLevels = New DataSet
        Dim psSql As String
        
        psSql = "SELECT [site].[LOCNCODE], [spl].PRCLEVEL FROM [dbo].[IV40700] [site] LEFT OUTER JOIN [cp].[SitePriceLevel] [spl] ON [site].[LOCNCODE] = [spl].[SiteId]"

        mdsPriceLevels = mobjGlobals.GetData(psSql)

        If mdsPriceLevels.IsSafe Then
            grdPriceLevels.DataSource = mdsPriceLevels.Tables(0)
            grdPriceLevels.Rows(0).Selected = True
        End If
    End Sub

    

    Private Sub grdPriceLevels_InitializeLayout(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs) Handles grdPriceLevels.InitializeLayout

        Try
            With Me.grdPriceLevels.DisplayLayout
                .ApplyDefaultPrismViewSettings()
                .Override.AllowUpdate = DefaultableBoolean.True

                
                .Bands(0).Columns("LOCNCODE").Header.VisiblePosition = 0
                .Bands(0).Columns("LOCNCODE").Header.Caption = "Site Id"
                .Bands(0).Columns("LOCNCODE").CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit

                .Bands(0).Columns("PRCLEVEL").Header.VisiblePosition = 1
                .Bands(0).Columns("PRCLEVEL").Header.Caption = "Price Level"
                .Bands(0).Columns("PRCLEVEL").Style = ColumnStyle.DropDownValidate
                .Bands(0).Columns("PRCLEVEL").ValueList = _vl          
                

            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorLogging.LogError(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Function GetPriceLevels() As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Dim sSql As String = "SELECT [PRCLEVEL] FROM [dbo].[IV40800]"

        Dim ds As DataSet = mobjGlobals.GetData(sSql)

        Dim list As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

        list.Add(String.Empty)

        If ds.IsSafe() Then
            For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                list.Add(row.Item("PRCLEVEL").ToString())
            Next
        End If

        Return list
    End Function

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    

    Private Sub btnSelect_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSelect.Click
        Dim sSql As String

        For Each row As UltraGridRow In grdPriceLevels.Rows
            If row.Cells("PRCLEVEL").Value Is Nothing OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells("PRCLEVEL").Value.ToString()) Then
                sSql = $"DELETE FROM [cp].[SitePriceLevel] WHERE [SiteId] = '{row.Cells("LOCNCODE").Value.ToString()}'"
                mobjGlobals.ExecuteDataByCommand(sSql, CommandType.Text, Nothing)
                Continue For
            End If

            sSql = $"UPDATE [cp].[SitePriceLevel] SET [PRCLEVEL] = '{row.Cells("PRCLEVEL").Value.ToString()}' WHERE [LOCNCODE] = '{row.Cells("LOCNCODE").Value.ToString()}'"
            If Not mobjGlobals.ExecuteDataByCommand(sSql, CommandType.Text, Nothing) Then
                sSql = $"INSERT INTO [cp].[SitePriceLevel] ([LOCNCODE], [PRCLEVEL]) VALUES ('{row.Cells("LOCNCODE").Value.ToString()}', '{row.Cells("PRCLEVEL").Value.ToString()}'"
                mobjGlobals.ExecuteDataByCommand(sSql, CommandType.Text, Nothing)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have checked and rechecked that the Value List is populated correctly. Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As we have default properties for the `UltraGrid` I had applied `.ApplyDefaultPrismViewSettings()`. When I removed that line it started working. This was my mistake.